# I only have a WSDL should I ask for an XSD too?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, biztalk

A third party has provided a WSDL. They are on a Java stack. I believe I need an XSD to be able to consume this in BizTalk via the "Add Generated Items-> Consume WCF Service". The 3rd party is not using WCF but this looks like the only option available for consuming the WSDL.

I am assuming I cannot consume the WSDL without the accompanying XSD. Am I correct?

Comment: I am confused; how is your accepted answer, answering your question?? You were confused to see an WSDL without an `accompanying` XSD file; the accepted answer tells you nothing more but what you've already stated. You should edit your question then to match your accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio will automatically generate the necessary BizTalk XSD file/s for you when you add a reference to the Web-Service WSDL. It will also add an orchestration with the necessary ports typed to the service's request and response messages (this orchestration can be safely deleted if it is not required).

As you have rightly pointed out, adding a service reference is achieved by selecting 'Add Generated Items -> Consume WCF Service' when you are consuming a WCF service, or 'Add Service Reference' if you are consuming a straight web-service.

You might also want to review some of the [MSDN documentation relating to the consuming of web-services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561062.aspx) in BizTalk, especially the [Specific Considerations when Consuming Web-Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561724.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Not really; whe XSD content may be embedded within the wsdl:types section of the WSDL file.